# What do you call the branches or offshoots of a cactus?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the branches or offshoots of a cactus? Cactus being a different plant altogether than trees, I am thinking they don't have branches, but I have no idea what they might be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call them **arms**; [a quick images search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cactus%20arms&ia=images&iax=images) shows that this term will be understood. [Ngrams shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cactus%20arms%2Ccactus%20arm%2Ccactus%20branches%2Ccactus%20branch&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccactus%20arms%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccactus%20arm%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccactus%20branches%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccactus%20branch%3B%2Cc0) that "branch" was much more common around 1900 but has declined; it is still used.

Comment: _Offshoots_ is fine as well. They can often be broken off and will grow roots and start another plant.